# My Angular ui modal cant find the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

here is my app , trying to use UI modal, but when the modal function cant find the html template. i can console log inside the function, but cant open a modal view.

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', [
        'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination',

    'ui.bootstrap'
    ]);


    app.controller('galleryCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    }]).
    controller('ModalInstanceCtrl',['$scope','$modal',function($scope, $modalInstance){

    }]).
    directive('myGallery', function ($http,$modal) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                feed: '@',
                search: '=?',
                resultsPerPage: "=?",
                sorting: "=?"
            },
            templateUrl: './MyGallery.tpl.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {


                scope.search = scope.search || true;
                scope.sorting = scope.sorting || true;
                scope.resultsPerPage = scope.resultsPerPage || 10;

                console.log(scope.resultsPerPage);

                scope.openModal = function() {


                    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                        templateUrl: '/views/modal.html',
                        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
                    });
                };
```

in the html:

```
<div class="imgs">
    <ul>
        <li dir-paginate="img in imgs
        | filter:query
        | itemsPerPage: resultsPerPage.value || 10 ">
               <a href=""><img ng-src="{{img.url}}" ng-click="openModal()"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and this is what i get :

```
 GET http://localhost:63342/views/modal.html 404 (Not Found)
```

the path is 100% correct , so if u guys can see what is the problem.

Comment: If you go directly to http://localhost:63342/views/modal.html in your browser, it pulls the template up?

Comment: No , thats the root : mainFolder -->views-->modal.html and the index.html in the mainFolder

Comment: Right.. So the path isn't correct.
What about 

```templateUrl: 'yourmainfolder/views/modal.html'```?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure.. try:

```
templateUrl: 'views/modal.html',
```

Maybe your local server's document root it's not where you think it is.

Getting rid of the initial slash you make sure the path is relative to the root folder of your angular project.

Comment: i get this without the / :  GET http://localhost:63342/front_testV2/template/modal/window.html 404 (Not Found) and i dont know this root at all . any ideas ?

Comment: You have to configure your server root to be the root of your angular project.